# The /etc/environment file is not executing certain commands

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Given below are the contents of my /etc/environment file

```
alias ...="cd ../../"
alias ls="ls -al"
export blah="blah blah"
```

When I start new terminal session and change to sudo user as `sudo su`, only the export command has run, which I am able to verify using env. The aliases are not set.

If I run `source /etc/environment` the aliases get set as expected. Am I missing something? I also read that /etc/environment is only read when the system boots. Is that true?

I am running on RHEL 7.

Comment: Which user should be able to use these entries?

Comment: I need the sudo user and myself to be able to use it. I can get that requirement from /etc/profile too right. But any idea why this is happening, as in the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/etc/environment` is intended for setting environment variables for every user on login. Therefore you don't need to use `export` in this file.

Adding `alias` into this file won't work, because this file is not a shell script and only accepts variable=value pairs.

> /etc/environment is used by the PAM-env module and is agnostic to
>   login/non-login, interactive/non-interactive and also Bash/non-Bash,
>   so scripting or glob expansion cannot be used. The file only accepts
>   variable=value pairs.

It's not possible to export aliases or set them globally - they need to be set again in every shell instance. 
The file you want to use is `~/.bashrc` in a home directory of a user. This file gets executed every time a user opens a bash shell. So aliases and variables set in this file will have effect only on that shell.

You can also use `/etc/bash.bashrc` which is System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash shells.

---

The reason why the `export` in your `/etc/environment` worked and actually created and env variable is that the pam-env parser specifically ignores `export` keyword to avoid confusion for people who don't know that `/etc/environment` is not a shell script.

You can see that in `pam_env.c` source code

```
/* skip over "export " if present so we can be compat with
   bash type declarations */
  if (strncmp(key, "export ", (size_t) 7) == 0)
      key += 7;
```

Its available for example [here - Linux-PAM/pam_env.c  v0.79](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/pam/0.79/modules_2pam__env_2pam__env_8c_source.html). See line `00234`.

Comment: Can you explain "Adding alias into this file won't work, because that needs to be processed in a shell that stays active."

Comment: Actually, I found that `/etc/environment` doesn't allow scripting at all. You can only set variables here.

Comment: `/etc/bash.bashrc` is not a standard system-wide configuration file. Some distributions source it from default `.bashrc` files created for new users.

Comment: @jmathews I think it didn't accept the export command, it just ignored it. It looks for valid Name=Value pairs that it can find in the file.

Comment: @KoCour `ls` was not set as an env variable.

Comment: @jmathews Check my edits to the answer, it explains what really happened.